# How to make your view transparent / display only the drawing in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-view

I have a class named `DrawView` which extends `View` and is on top of a `TableLayout`. I'm using this class to draw 1 simple line using the `drawLine()` method. My `TableLayout` is being overdrawn because my `DrawView` class is on top of it. How can I prevent this? My line needs to be on top of the `TableLayout`, said line isn't using the whole canvas, so I thought setting the background to transparent would fix it, which isn't the case.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private static int orientation;
    private static int pos;
    public static final int HORIZONTAL = 1;
    public static final int VERTICAL = 2;
    public static final int DIAGONAL = 3;
    public static final int TOP_LEFT = 4;
    public static final int TOP_RIGHT = 5;

    private void init() {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(25f);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public static void setOrientation(int newOrientation) {
        orientation = newOrientation;
    }

    public static void setPosition(int newPosition) {
        pos = newPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        final int INDENT = 147;
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        switch (orientation) {
            case HORIZONTAL:
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        canvas.drawLine(10, INDENT, getWidth() - 10, INDENT, paint);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        canvas.drawLine(10, INDENT * 3, getWidth() - 10, INDENT * 3, paint);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        canvas.drawLine(10, INDENT * 5, getWidth() - 10, INDENT * 5, paint);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case VERTICAL:
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        canvas.drawLine(INDENT, 10, INDENT, getHeight() - 10, paint);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        canvas.drawLine(INDENT * 3, 10, INDENT * 3, getHeight() - 10, paint);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        canvas.drawLine(INDENT * 5, 10, INDENT * 5, getHeight() - 10, paint);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case DIAGONAL:
                if (pos == TOP_LEFT) {
                    canvas.drawLine(10, 10, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 10, paint);
                } else if (pos == TOP_RIGHT) {
                    canvas.drawLine(10, getHeight() - 10, getWidth() - 10, 10, paint);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

This view is also invisible, until I call this method:

```
public void displayResult(int result) {
        // TODO: Fix board being overdrawn by DrawView
        DrawView drawView = new DrawView(this);
        //drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        drawView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        /*...*/
    }
```

But it still overdraws my `TableLayout`.
This is how my layout looks if the DrawView is under the TableLayout, as one can guess no line will displayed:

[image: Layout with DrawView under TableLayout]

And this is how my layout looks if the DrawView is above the TableLayout, this way I get a line with a white background which completely overdraws my TableLayout:

[image: Layout with DrawView above TableLayout]

**How can I make sure only the line is drawn without the white background of it?**

Comment: I tried recreating this but it works fine on my pc. In my project i drew a line in front of some text which is inside of a table layout. My canvas has a transparent background by default and setting it to Color.Transparent doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my shame, the background of the layout, in which my view (`DrawView`) is, was set to white. Therefore my view also had a white canvas, thus overdrawing my TableLayout.

While this might be an underwhelming answer, it might help someone who comes along this in the future.

**Check your layout's background.**